# How to use android SDK of android studio in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

As Xamarin needed Android SDK so put the path of android studio's Android SDK in it but then this error occurred so it showed this page. I wanted to do this because i want to save disk space on my hard disk i do not want to have separate android SDK for separate software.

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOfw3.png)

Comment: i could not accomplish it so i had to copy the android SDK from the location of android studio to the location of Xamarin. So i saved my download time but could not save disk space. If anyone can still solve my question please do write a answer below.

Comment: Follow the instructions for [manual installation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/). There are directions there to configure Xamarin.Android.

Comment: I wanted to use the Android SDK from the location of Android studio but xamarin did not use that location and needed a copy of Android SDK in the location of xamarin. So I was not able to save disk space. I had followed the manual instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my PC, I have android studio and vs2015 share the same android sdk.

Android Studio:

[image]

Virtual Studio：

[image]

Just move your android studio sdk to a correct path and set both IDE Android SDK Location with the same path.

Comment: @Anant_infinity if the answer helped you, please remember mark it as an answer thanks.